# How can I store the output using lapply in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, shiny-reactivity, selectinput

I am building an app which allows the user to submit a formation of football players. The player names are stored in a .csv file. These names are read in and are then the input for the select inputs. The user is supposed to first select a formation and then depending on the selected formation the select inputs with the names appear. This works pretty well (in the example below with 2 select inputs) by using lapply.
My problem is now that I would like to store the selected names in a variable to further use them. The variable myval is supposed to store the selected name. It somehow only works with the first selected name of the first select input.

What I mean is that this works and stores the name selected in the first select input:

```r
     myval <- eventReactive(input$i[1],
                                 {input$i[1]})
```

But this doesn't work:

```r
     myval <- eventReactive(input$i[2],
                                 {input$i[2]})
```

Below you can find the full code.
Many thanks in advance!

ui.R:

```r
    fluidPage(
    #Dropdown
      selectInput("Formation", label = "Formation", choice = c("",433,343)),
    #Output
      uiOutput(outputId = "select_formation")
    )
```

server.R:

```r
    function(input, output, session){
    
    #input_names <- read.csv("temp.csv",TRUE,";")
    input_names <- structure(list(Goalkeeper = c("-", "Max", "Mo", "Tobi", "", "", 
""), Defender = c("-", "Bob", "Julius", "Mat", "Hans", "Peter", 
"Tom")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

    output$select_formation = renderUI(
        if(input$Formation == 433){      
          lapply(1:2,function(i){
          selectInput(inputId = "i", label = names(input_names[i]), choices = c(input_names[,i]))
          })
        })

      myval <- eventReactive(input$i[2],
                             {input$i[2]}) 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing the data. Here is a working example that might be helpful.

The `inputId` for the dynamically created `selectInput` is created by `paste0("id", i)` so you will have `id1` and `id2` in your example.

Your `myval` `reactive` expression can obtain a list of the input values through `lapply` again, using the same ids for reference.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Formation", label = "Formation", choice = c("",433,343)),
  uiOutput(outputId = "select_formation"),
  uiOutput("select_inputs")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$select_formation = renderUI(
    if(input$Formation == 433){      
      lapply(1:2, function(i){
        selectInput(inputId = paste0("id", i), label = names(input_names[i]), choices = c(input_names[i]))
      })
    })
  
  myval <- reactive({
    lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      input[[paste0("id", i)]]
    })
  })
                         
  output$select_inputs <- renderUI({
    paste("You selected: ", paste(myval(), collapse = ", "))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow thanks for responding so quickly. I will try it out and let you know :D !

Comment: Works perfectly and is exactly what i've searched for. Thanks Ben!